# Input 'touched' in angular validation is blocking method execution

Tags: javascript, angular

I noticed when using this kind of validation:

```
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.password.touched && f.password.errors }" />

  <div *ngIf="f.password.touched && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="alertX()">sdf</button>
</div>
```

When I focused the input and then click the button, the method 'alertX()' **is not executed** I think it is because the state for the input changes to **touched=true** before the alertX(), (this happens sometimes not always but is kinda annoying for UX) any advice how to avoid this behaviour would be appreciated...
[Example of method not executed when input was focused the button was clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2pj5.png)

Comment: Can you share the Stackblitz link please. I see in your screenshot you have a StackBlitz.

Comment: I created a stackBlitz and it works every time. Can you reproduce it in this example?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-6p3vry?file=src/app/formreactive/formreactive.component.ts

Comment: I tried your stackblitz and still it happens... I wonder how you can not reproduce it, weird..   https://prnt.sc/1077k27

Comment: I reread your question and realised it was indeed the case. Added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event):

> click fires after both the mousedown and mouseup events have fired, in
> that order.

In your example, clicking on the button causes the `mousedown`. This fires the validation immediately and there is an error under the input.

This moves the button a little lower and the `mouseup` is no longer on the button! So the click event doesn't fire since you didn't `mouseup` on the button.

Workaround:

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" (mousedown)="alertX()">Register</button>
```

Register a EventListener on mouse down rather than a 'click' event to fire.

[Working Demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-6p3vry?file=src%2Fapp%2Fformreactive%2Fformreactive.component.html)